# Magento 2 Soap API with Web Service Studio Client?

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I am programing an API Client with Filemaker and MBS Plug-in.

With Magento1 Soap API I could use a client called "Web Service Studio" https://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/ to try things out. Later i could use the XML a use within Filemaker.

Using an URL under Magento1 like

```
www.url.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl
```

gave me a result with which I could request a Token and could login with token I got.

To request a Token within Magento2 Soap Api I found this URL:

```
www.url.com/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1
```

If I request a WSDL like I did before like

```
www.url.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1
```

I only get a 401 Unauthorised.

So where do I place my token or where do I get a WSDL like before in Magento1?

Answer (score 0):

Try to request a token within Magento 2.

Then add the authorization token in the HTTP header

```
Authorization: Bearer YOURTOKEN
```

With this URL : www.url.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1

**Documentation reference :**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html

Code example in PHP :

```
<?php
$opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer 36849300bca4fbff758d93a3379f1b8e'
            )
        );
$wsdlUrl = 'http://magento.ll/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=testModule1AllSoapAndRestV1';
$serviceArgs = array("id"=>1);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);

$soapResponse = $soapClient->testModule1AllSoapAndRestV1Item($serviceArgs); ?>
```

Comment: I guess that is the problem, I dont find a way to chnage the header in this programm. Is there a way to add the token into the URL?

Comment: No it is an HTTP header. You can test your webservice with SOAP UI. You can change the header.

Comment: I got it: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#1-Custom-HTTP-Headers

Comment: So its working ?

Comment: Yes that works. Would be nice to have it in "Web Service Studio" because the GUI is not that complex.

Comment: SoapUi is powerfull and I think also intuitive. do not hesitate to close this topic so.

Comment: It seams that Soap UI has no GUI like WSS programm, so that does not really help. The point of WSS is that you simply load the WSDL and then you login and simply change values to see what hapends after that you simply copy the xml and changebthe values to variables and you are ready in your acpi client. With SOAP UI i only see xml lists so far (?)

Comment: Check with WSS to add authentication header or check extra feature with SoapUI. Moreover WSS seems not documented and is not multiplatform ?

Comment: I'm using Magento CE 2.2.0. When creating the new SoapClient object, do not use key "context".  It gives in response "Unauthorized" even if username, password and token is valid. Instead use "stream_context" as key and store the context object with token in it's value.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to add the

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

to run it directly in WSS. So I found a way arround. I did load a WSDL page like

```
www.url.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1
```

into SOAP UI and then after saving it as .wsdl I could load it into WebServiceStudio.